# Swift "Is" Type Check Operator

Tags: swift, types

I ran into a problem when I was learning "Is" type check operator in Swift.  I tried following codes in my Xcode and the results printed in console really made me confused.

```
class Animal {}
class Dog: Animal {}
let dog: Animal = Dog()
let anotherDog = Dog()

print("\(dog.dynamicType)") //printed "(Dog #1)"

if dog is Animal {
   print("dog is an Animal") //printed
}

if dog is Dog {
   print("dog is a dog") //printed
 }

if anotherDog is Animal {
   print("another dog is an Animal") //printed
}
```

Here are my confusions：

#### *1.*

I learned following programming style from Apple's Blog. https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=23  I don't know whether this is a good programming style because swift can do type inference.

```
let dog: Animal = Dog()
```

#### *2.*

I guess (anInstance).dynamicType may be a runtime feature to check the type of the instance. However, there is no related methods that I can call on it. So how could I use it?

#### *3.*

```
let dog: Animal = Dog()
```

What exactly is the type of dog instance? Animal or Dog? Does the "Is" operator check both compiler time type(Animal) and runtime type(Dog) of a instance? Or even my understanding of complier time type and runtime type is wrong?

Comment: Can you help me with this?@NicolasMiari :]

Comment: did you do some reading on the object orientend concept of polymorphism?

Comment: @ChristianDietrich Sorry for the wrong expression. Polymorphism is saying about the calling of methods. I will correct this in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the reference dog is Animal. Thus you can hand it to api that uses Animals. But the actual type behind the dog reference will be Dog. thus you can test for the actual type using `is` and you can (down)cast to the actual type using `as`

Comment: Could you please provide me more details, because what you've said is hard to understand.

Comment: Now I understand it. "Is" will check the target which the reference points to, and the reference is used for parameter passing in api.